# Como editar el footer de un Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

quiero poner los enlaces de la política de privacidad y de cookies en el footer de mi web: http://depeliculas.online/ , pero el tema que utilizo no tiene el footer como widget por lo que tengo que tocar el código. Se que el problema de esto es que cuando se actualice el tema desaparecerá mi edición pero puedo ir cambiándolo con cada actualización. Tengo algunos conocimientos básicos de PHP pero no estoy seguro de que parte tengo que editar.
Cualquiera que me pueda ayudar se lo agradecería.

Comment: Hola, investiga sobre la etiqueta `<footer>` de HTML, tendrías que añadirla dentro del `<body>` de tu web al final de todo y luego darle forma con CSS para que tenga un estilo parecido al del tema que estas usando.

Comment: ¿Has visto la documentación de Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola De Películas Online, espero que estes teniendo un buen día.

**No es recomendable** que toques el tema que has comprado. **Jamás lo toques**, porque una vez actualizado se va a perder todo.

Debes buscar el [**childthemes**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) del tema que has comprado, que por lo regular, viene junto al ZIP. Aqui una guía que te puede ser útil: http://gooddesign.es/instalacion-y-configuracion-del-tema-hijo-child-theme-css-y-php/

Una vez tienes el *childtheme*, debes de ir al tema orginal  copiar el *footer.php*  pegarlo en la carpeta del *childtheme*, entonces **ahora si puedes modificar con toda seguridad** y sabiendo que no perderás tus modificaciones.

Espero que te funcione, un saludo!

Comment: Gracias por tu repuesta Raylin, pero al final he editado directamente el archivo footer.php, al ser un cambio simple creo que hubiera tardado demasiado en hacerlo de la forma correcta. Tengo guardados el archivo original y el editado por si acaso. Aunque como dices esta el problema de que tengo que editarlo con cada actualización del tema. Pero tendré tu consejo presente para futuras modificaciones.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido :D

Answer (score 1):

Concuerdo con Raylin en que jamás debes tocar el tema padre.
Revisa como hacer un tema hijo(se tarda apenas 2 minutos en confeccionarlo y te dará la vida cuando actualices):
https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Temas_hijos

Eso por una parte.

Por otra parte, para agregar un widget area nuevo sin dolores de cabeza, puedes emplear algún plugin existente. P.ej.,

https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/content-aware-sidebars/

Una vez confeccionado el tema hijo y agregado el widget area en el footer, lo que queda es agregar el enlace a las páginas informativas de cookies y politica de privacidad.

Para ello confecciona las páginas como harías para crear cualquier otra página. Y luego pegas el enlace en ese widget area creando un widget de texto, y:

- escribiendo el enlace en la pestaña de html (utilizando html para crear el enlace), o bien
- en el modo "visual" utilizando el icono de la cadenita (que es la forma de incluuir un enlace)

Answer (score -1):

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es buscar un plugin que haga lo que necesitas, sin necesidad de tocar el codigo o crear un childtheme